# How to read sub group values from .ini file in java?

Tags: java, php, ini

i  have .ini file with following structure:

```
    [HEADING1][SUBHEADING]
    DBUSer=John
    DBPASSWD=Joe1234
```

i am not able to read values from the subgroup(SUBHEADING) of group (HEADING1).I tried hard to search not net but not find any hint, please share your view on that.

i am able to read .ini file with this structure:

```
    [HEADING1]
    DBUSer=John
    DBPASSWD=Joe1234
```

but for subgroup i am facing problem.

```
   Ini ini = new Ini(new File("/path/to/file"));
   System.out.println(ini.get("HEADING1", "DBUSer"));
```

or if you have any other solution or library please share it here.

Comment: What library are you using and why is your question tagged PHP?

Comment: Are you sure ini files are supporting sub headings ? I just took a look int ini file spec and can't find such information.

Comment: @DirkLachowski I am using ini4j library for this and i tagged PHP because .ini file use most in php.

Comment: @ArkadiuszWojcik i also checked but not able to get any info,ini files are supporting sub headings or not.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but according to the documentation this should be possible by using the TreeModel:

```
Ini ini = new Ini(new File("/path/to/file"));
System.out.println(ini.get("HEADING1/SUBHEADING", "DBUSer"));
```

You can find a sample [here](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/xref-test/org/ini4j/tutorial/IniTutorial.html) ( method `sample05()` ).