# Spliting String into sections with keywords

Tags: java, string

I have a String i read from a .txt file with has values in sections seperated like

```
Text first 
[section_name_1]
Text with values pattern1
...
[section_name_2]
Text with values pattern2
```

I need to split the sections at the **section_name_#** marks and add those to a **String []** (Size of the array is fixed). My Code by now does not make some weird output:

```
//Code:
public static String[] parseFileToParams(File file)
    {
        String[] sections= {"[section_name_1]","[section_name_2]","[section_name_3]","[section_name_4]"};
        String[] params = new String[sections.length+1];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String decoded = parseFile(file);// Returns the Text from the file
        for(int i=0; i< sections.length;i++)
        {
            params[i]= decoded.split(sections[i])[1];
            sb.append(params[i]);
        }
        return params; 
    }
//For Test of the output
String[] textArray = BasicOsuParser.parseFileToParams(parseFile);
        for(int j = 0; j<textArray.length;j++)
        {
            sb.append(textArray[j]);
        }
        String text= sb.toString();
System.out.println (text); //Output: su f form formau fnull
// Obviously not how it should look like
```

**Thanks for help!**

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490450/how-to-read-sub-group-values-from-ini-file-in-java

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code ??

Comment: @iRavi iVooda I can't debug because I'm kinda forced to develop on my android phone

Comment: @RC. How does this help me when I'm not using a .ini?

Comment: @risingprogrammer tour text sample looks like ini format to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] sections= {"[section_name_1]","[section_name_2]","[section_name_3]","[section_name_4]"};
        String textFromFile = "Text first [section_name_1] Text with values pattern1 [section_name_2] Text with values pattern2";
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
            if(textFromFile.contains(sections[i])){//Use this to tell how big the parms array will be.
                count++;
            }
            sections[i] = sections[i].replace("[", "\\[").replace("]", "\\]");//Removes the brackets from being delimiters.
        }
        String[] parms = new String[count+1];//Where the split items will go.
        int next = 0;//The next index for the parms array.
        for(String sec : sections){
            String split[] = textFromFile.split(sec);//Split the file's text by the sec
            if(split.length == 2){
                parms[next] = split[0];//Adds split to the parms
                next++;//Go to the next index for the parms.
                textFromFile = split[1];//Remove text which has just been added to the parms.
            }
        }
        parms[next] = textFromFile;//Add any text after the last split.
        for(String out : parms){
            System.out.println(out);//Output parms.
        }
```

This will do what you have asked and it is commented so you can see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea use `split()` only for a one delimiter in text. This method tries to separate the text by given regexp pattern and usually used where there are more than one given delimiter in the text. Also you should screen special symbols in reqexp like '.','[' and so on. [read about patterns in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). In your case better use `substring()` and `indexOf()`:

```
public static String[] parseFileToParams(File file)
{
    String[] sections= {"[section_name_1]","[section_name_2]","[section_name_3]","[section_name_4]"};
    String[] params = new String[sections.length+1];
    String decoded = parseFile(file);// Returns the Text from the file
    int sectionStart = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
        int sectionEnd = decoded.indexOf(sections[i], sectionStart);
        params[i] = decoded.substring(sectionStart, sectionEnd);
        sectionStart = sectionEnd + sections[i].length();
    }
    params[sections.length] = decoded.substring(sectionStart, decoded.length());
    return params; 
}
```

Comment: This however throws a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Still, I'll try to use substring and indexOf for performance

Answer (score 0):

```
params[i]= decoded.split(sections[i])[1];
```

This returns the string after the first appearance of the sections[i] i.e. not just until the section[i+1] but till the end of file.

Answer (score 0):

This loop,
    `for(int i=0; i< sections.length;i++)
        {
            params[i]= decoded.split(sections[i])[1];
            sb.append(params[i]);
        }
        return params;`
Repeatedly splits decoded into 2 halves, separated by the given section. You then append the entire 2nd half into params.
Example, pretend you wanted to split the string "abcdef" along "a", "b", etc.
You would split along a, and append "bcdef" to params, then split along b, and append "cdef" to params, etc., so you would get "bcdefcdef...f".
I think what you want to do is use real regex as the delimiter, something like `params = decoded.split([section_name_.])`. Look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx
and if you want t